# how to add context menu through java

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to add a context(Right Click like open) menu in Eclipse plugin development through Java.I am able to do it through Plugin.xml but i want to add through Java.What is the way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually prefer to use either the `class` attribute of the `menuContribution` or alternatively the `dynamic` element... Using these, means you will have all you contributions in just one place...

If you really want to use Java, have a look at the interface of `MenuManager`. You simply add your context menu as always and the add the menu items using `add(IContributionItem)` (and possibly `add(Action)`).

There are a long list of `IContributionItem` implementations to get inspired from. Some of the more interesting are:

- `CommandContributionItem` - used to add a command as declared with the `commands` extension point
- `ControlContribution` - as a way to add any `Control` to a toolbar
- `CompoundContributionItem` - a way to compute the contributions late